# FileFilter for JFileChooser has compilation errors

Tags: java, swing, file, filter, jfilechooser

Eclipse shows two errors:

- The method addChoosableFileFilter in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileNameExtensionFilter to FileFilter
  whats the error, i cant find it?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF Documents", "pdf");
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have imported `javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to import `javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter` instead of `java.io.FileFilter`